# Modify Default properties on Paraview Properties Panel (5.7.0)

Tags: c++, paraview

I try to modify the default value of a property in Paraview using a custom Plugin. 
When I add a Dicom file in my pipeline, the default representation is set to "`Outline`" in the property panel, but I want it to be "`Volume`".
The goal is to interact with existing properties in Paraview

I git clone the paraview repository, and I used CMake to get the .sln file and compile it with Visual Studio. I do the same with example plugin provided by Paraview itself (like the toolbar or property widget to understand how it works), everything works for now.
But when I try to set the data representation to "volume", nothing work (no results, it still uniform.)

What i've tried (from my plugin):

```
pqApplicationCore* applicationCore = pqApplicationCore::instance();
pqObjectBuilder* objectBuilder = applicationCore->getObjectBuilder();
pqServerManagerModel* serverManagerModel =  applicationCore->getServerManagerModel();

if (serverManagerModel->getNumberOfItems<pqServer*>() == 1)
  {
    // Getting the first (and only) server
    pqServer* server = serverManagerModel->getItemAtIndex<pqServer*>(0);

    //Creating a reader for dicom files
    pqPipelineSource* pipelineSource =
      objectBuilder->createReader("sources", "DICOMReader", { file }, server);

    // Getting the first view
    pqView* v = serverManagerModel->getItemAtIndex<pqView*>(0);

    // Setting the data representation to Volume, at least, i try to set it.
    pqDataRepresentation* data = objectBuilder->createDataRepresentation(
      pipelineSource->getOutputPorts().at(0), v, "UniformGridRepresentation");

    // SOLUTION 
    vtkSMPVRepresentationProxy::SetScalarColoring(data->getProxy(), "DICOMImage", vtkDataObject::POINT);
    pqSMAdaptor::setEnumerationProperty(data->getProxy()->GetProperty("Representation"), "Volume");

    // wrong
    data->setProperty("VolumeRendering", "volume");

    data->setVisible(true);
}
```

CMakeList.txt

```
set(interfaces)
set(sources
  MyToolBar.cxx
  MyToolBar.h
  MyToolBarActions.cxx
  MyToolBarActions.h)

paraview_plugin_add_action_group(…….)

paraview_plugin_add_toolbar(…..)

paraview_add_plugin(pluginName 
  VERSION "1.0"
  UI_INTERFACES ${interfaces}
  SOURCES ${sources})

target_link_libraries(cmakePluginName PRIVATE ParaView::ServerManagerRendering)
```

I expected the "Representation" field to be on "Volume" but still in "Outline"
I also tried to change the "UniformGridRepresentation" to something else, with no results, except weird things and crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your plugin have an XML file describing the DICOM reader?

Comment: Nope, i'm using the default DICOM reader provided by paraview. @CoryQuammen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setProperty` you used concern Qt property (this class inherits from QObject) and not ParaView Proxy property.

you should replace this line with the following:

*edit: add the SetScalarColoring part*

```
vtkSMPVRepresentationProxy::SetScalarColoring(data->getProxy(), <ArrayName>, vtkDataObject::POINT);
pqSMAdaptor::setEnumerationProperty(data->getProxy()->GetProperty("Representation"), "Volume");
```

`<ArrayName>` is the data you want to use for coloration. If not specified, a unique `Solid Color` is used but it is not available for volume rendering.

`vtkDataObject::POINT` can also be `vtkDataObject::CELL` if `<ArrayName>` is associated to the cells and not to the points.

Comment: Hmmmm it seem to work, but not totally … the representation is set to volume, but there is nothing in the central view… and i cannot apply something. If i go to an other representation to come back to "volume" it work … 
how it is possible ?

Comment: you may have to specify the array to use for coloring. Add `vtkSMPVRepresentationProxy::SetScalarColoring(data->getProxy(), <ArrayName>, vtkDataObject::POINT);` before the `pqSMAdaptor::...` line.
And replace <ArrayName> with the variable to use for coloring and maybe change `vtkDataObject::POINT` with `vtkDataObject::CELL`, depending on your data

Comment: I'm really trying … but for some reasons i cannot include ```vtkSMPVRepresentationProxy``` (not found) . I check the paraview Doxygen and the class exist. ```vtkSMRepresentationProxy``` dont work either, but ```vtkSMSourceProxy``` and upper work. (```vtkDataObject``` also work)
So you mean my representation exist but don't have any color, so i cant see it ?
The array name you mean is an array containing vtk color ?

Comment: * array name : Indeed. It is not exactly the vtk color but the data used for coloration (through a lookup table, see the color map editor).

* build problem: Did you add `ParaView::ServerManagerRendering` in the REQUIRES_MODULE section of your paraview.plugin ? If yes, I will need more info about your build (exact version of PV, OS, CMake options you explicitly specified, paraview.plugin file ...)

Comment: I try with ```ParaView::ServerManagerRendering``` but nothing change
OS: Windows 10

PV version: 5.7.0 (-500g40ccdb1b02 when build with cmake)
CMake option: I dont touch anything exept Paraview_DIR since Qt5 is in my PATH
paraview.plugin:
```NAME
  pluginName
DESCRIPTION
  pluginDesc
REQUIRES_MODULES
  ParaView::pqComponents
  ParaView::ServerManagerRendering
```

Comment: In the inner CMakeLists.txt of your plugin, where you should have a `paraview_add_plugin(...)` call, you also should have a `target_link_libraries(<TargetName> PRIVATE ParaView::ServerManagerRendering)` (and maybe other arguments)

Comment: Okay, you were right. i did not have the ```target_lin_libraries``` and i put it AFTER the ```paraview_add_plugin```
For ArrayName i put "DICOMImage"
Thanks for your help ! =)